# Problema ao salvar número de itens lidos em variavel

Tags: python, python-3.x

O código tem a ideia de apenas ler quantas vezes se repetem o maior valor do array.

```
num_velas = int(input('Número de velas: '))
alturaVelas = []
alturaVelas = input('Qual a altura das velas?').strip().split() #altura das velas dada em cm
alturaVelasCrescente = sorted(alturaVelas)

velasRetiraveis = alturaVelasCrescente.count(max(alturaVelas)) #o usuário pode retirar apenas as velas mais altas.

print(str(velasRetiraveis))
```

Ao realizar um teste com 100000(cem mil) entradas sendo UM valor de entrada 999 e todas as outras entradas são de 1000.
Deveria registrar **99999** vezes o valor '1000' e uma vez o valor de '999'.
Saberiam me dizer o por que de dar erro?

Não consegui reproduzir o erro no pycharm pois é um número muito alto de inputs, o emulador que testou não retorna o erro.

Comment: Você não converteu as alturas para int, então elas continuam sendo string; assim 999 é maior que 1000, pois será considerado a ordem alfabética, visto que 1 vem antes do 9.

Comment: Converta a altura da vela para int().